# How do I parameterize getParameterNames to avoid the warning

Tags: java, servlets

```
    HttpServletRequest request;
    Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
```

How should I declare the return type for the above method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [ServletRequest API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) (since `HttpServletRequest` inherits this method from its super interface, `ServletRequest`) and it will tell you what this method returns: `java.util.Enumeration<java.lang.String>`, meaning you might wish to try:

```
HttpServletRequest request;
Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
```

**Edit 1:**
I'm not sure why you're getting the first error. Perhaps you must cast the value returned from the method?

```
HttpServletRequest request;
Enumeration<String> params = (Enumeration<String>)request.getParameterNames();
```

But to be honest, while I"m pretty good at going through most API's, I don't do servlets and would appreciate any help from the experts here.

Comment: - Type safety: The expression of type Enumeration needs unchecked conversion to conform to 
  Enumeration<String>
 - Enumeration is a raw type. References to generic type Enumeration<E> should be parameterized

Comment: The second warning is gone from the above list, the first warning still remains.

Comment: @Jason: please see **Edit 1:** in my answer above.

Answer (score 10):

This method was parameterized since [Servlet API 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames%28%29) (Java EE 6). In older versions like [Servlet API 2.5](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames%28%29) (Java EE 5) and before this method (and many others) is not parameterized. You're apparently running a Servlet 2.5 container or older. You have basically 2 options:

1. Upgrade to a Servlet 3.0 container ([Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [Glassfish 3](http://glassfish.java.net/), [JBoss AS 6](http://jboss.org/jbossas), etc) so that you can do

   ```
   Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
   ```
2. Make an unchecked cast.

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   Enumeration<String> params = (Enumeration<String>) request.getParameterNames();
   ```

Comment: What if the file is a jsp file and not a java one? You can't do supresswarning there.

Comment: @elvenbyte: Java code doesn't belong in a JSP file anyway. Just move it to a Java class.

Comment: Too much work for a simple thing sometimes..., there must be a solution for this, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what method you referred to, but to suppress warnings for the method or for the statement put this in front of it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

It must be either before method declaration or before assignment statement.